# jQuery Adding/Removing class according to page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a code snippet that I use in my websites to display a Call to Action btn when the user scrolls down a webpage. But its not working in one of my websites. I have researched and couldn't find an error. Here's the [link to the page I am using this code](https://eyusatzpcq29rujb-9315549265.shopifypreview.com/collections/relogios-masculino/products/relogio-nibosi-inox-masculino). Why JS is not adding the class "atcbottomactive" to the element?

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 1100) {
        $(".atcbottom").addClass("atcbottomactive");
    } else {
        $(".atcbottom").removeClass("atcbottomactive");
    }
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:1000px) {
 
    .atcbottom {
        display: none!important
    }
    .btnn {
        margin-top: -60px!important
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:999px) {
    .atcbottomactivepopup {
        margin-bottom: 60px
    }
}


.atcbottom {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 102;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: -100px;
    transition: 2s;
    left: 0;
}

.atcbtn {
    height: 40px;
    background: #4cae4c;
    width: 90vw;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.atcbottomactive {
    bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px; width: 100%; background: blue">

<div class='atcbottom'>
      <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
          <a href="#ProductPrice-product-template">
          <button type="button" class="atcbtn">Call to action</button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pure **Javascript**, here is an example that I wrote it just for you.
Hope that my code would be useful!

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
  e=(e||window.event);
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const topOffset=window.scrollY;
  document.querySelector("#scrollOffset").innerHTML="ScrollTop: "+topOffset+"px";
  
  if(topOffset> 100 ){
    document.querySelector(".box").classList.add("scrollEffect");
  
  }else document.querySelector(".box").classList.remove("scrollEffect");
  
});
```

```css
span#scrollOffset{
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.box{

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  
}

.box.scrollEffect{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body style="min-height: 200vh">
  <span id="scrollOffset">ScrollTop: 0px</span><br>
  <div class="box">This box class must change when scroll even fires !</div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your website, and open my developer console, I see these errors:

[image]

It seems jQuery is available on your site, but for some reason is not saved to the variable `$`. You have to access it with the `jQuery` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am just starting with JS and JQuery, how should I access with the JQuery variable?

Comment: Use `jQuery` instead of `$`. For example, instead of `$(".atcbottom").removeClass("atcbottomactive");`, write `jQuery(".atcbottom").removeClass("atcbottomactive");`.

Comment: I made the changes but it didnt work: https://eyusatzpcq29rujb-9315549265.shopifypreview.com/collections/relogios-masculino/products/relogio-nibosi-inox-masculino , the same error keep appearing on console aswell

Comment: `$` shows up in several other places in your code, such as `$(window).scroll(function() {`. Make sure you get all of them.

Comment: I have replaced all `$` to `jQuery` and now the console displays the error with `jQuery`

Comment: It looks like jQuery isn't loaded until after this code has already been run. You might look at this article to add jQuery to your site: http://www.expertshopify.com/shopify-code-snippets/adding-jquery-to-a-shopify-theme/

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your site, in the dev console it says that it doesn't reconize the $ sign. You could change the $ sign to jQuery. but if you want to use the $ sign you'll need to load the slim.min version of jquery.